# Default value for h:inputText

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

Imagine a text box, bound to a ManagedBean:

```
<h:inputText id="name" value="#{mb.name}"/>
```

I would like to default the field to a value.

I know I can set the value in the ManagedBean at construction time, but that doesn't work for me as I use the same ManagedBean as a backing bean in different xhtml pages.  And I don't want the 'name' field to be initialized in *all* those pages.

Can somebody suggest a strategy?  Or am I missing something essential?

Thank you very much!
J.

Comment: Using **JSF Converter** to convert the value from long, int, double ...etc to Wrapper Data types
Long, Integer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- you can fill the value in with javascript (`document.getElementById("formName:textName").value = 'defaultValue';`. Perhaps on `document.onload`
- you can subclass your managed bean and fill the default value in the default constructor, or in a `@PostConstruct` method, and use the subclassed bean.

Comment: Thx Bozho.  

The JavaScript answer does the trick!

I don't think that the alternative (@PostConstruct) works for me. I'm using viewparams and because of the name matching involved, the bean name in from-view needs to equal the bean name in the to-view.  

However, do you think I could detect the name of the calling *.xhtml page by inspecting some context object?  I explored FacesContext using the debugger, but I couldn't find a typesafe way to get the from-view from the Request object.  Anyway, this approach doesn't look as clean as the JavaScript one.  Just curious. ;-)

Thx. J.

Comment: You can, using `getViewRoot().getViewId()`. Btw, if an answer works for you - mark it as accepted (tick below the vote counter)